# Assigning array - "cannot convert from double* to double[]"

Tags: c++, arrays

I've been doing this problem for a good few hours now so the answer might be obvious and I'm missing it, but I keep getting the errors:
C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'double *' to 'double[7]'
IntelliSense: expression must be a modifiable lvalue

Heres the code having the issues:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

class SnowData
{
private:
    int dates[7];
    double inches[7];
    string monthName;
    int startdate;
public:
    SnowData(string _monthName, int _startdate, double* _inches)
    {
        inches = _inches;
        monthName = _monthName;
        startdate = _startdate;
    }
```

I just need to get the `_inches` from my constructor into my `inches` array and I can finally finish this problem.

Comment: Arrays are not assignable. Use `std::array`.

Comment: Oh, you should probably use a constructor initializer list as well. As it is, each member is being default-initialized and then assigned to instead of simply being initialized to the parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like @chris said, you cannot assign arrays. However, you can assign individual elements (provided they have an appropriate `=` operator).

```
for(int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
    inches[i] = _inches[i];
}
```

This iterates through `inches` and assigns every element with a corresponding on in `_inches`.

**Warning:** undefined behavior is `_inches` size is less than 7.

Comment: `std::copy(_n)` does this, so you can use that, too.

Comment: Thanks this fixed my problem, I should have known to do this, but my lack of sleep has me unable to think properly >.<

Comment: Yeah I just had to wait the minimum time to mark resolved first.

Answer (score 0):

If you must use a low-level array, then you'll probably want to copy the elements individually from the input array to the member array. You can't just assign the pointer value to the array.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign an array that way. You should add the numbers of "_inches" pointed by _inches in your method, and use memcopy that way :

```
memcpy(inches, _inches, _inches_count * sizeof(double));
```

And do not forget to check that _inches_count is smaller than 7 !

Comment: In this case it is, but it's too easy to take something that works in one case and incorrectly apply it to another.

Comment: use `std::copy` in C++, `memcpy` is only for C code